# What is an efficient way to access large-ish datasets using JDBC with Clojure

Tags: jdbc, clojure, processing-efficiency

#### EDIT

N00b problem as it turns out. I didn't realize that running `lein ring server` results in your app being ran in interpreted mode, which is why it was much slower.

---

Can the following Clojure/ JDBC fragment be optimized so that it runs (much) faster?

```
(defn test-sql []
  (sql/with-connection (db-connection)
    (sql/with-query-results results ["select * from users order by username asc"]
        (doseq [row results ] 
          (println "User" (row :first_name) (row :last_name)) results))))
```

I am considering using Clojure for an ETL project. First test I wrote was to print out data from a table I have with ~280K records in it. The implementations I came up with so far have been quite slow; what takes ~12 seconds in Java (even using myBatis to populate objects rather than 'raw' access) takes ~9.5 minutes with my Clojure solution.

I tried map instead of doseq, and tried using a cursor like outlined here: http://asymmetrical-view.com/2010/10/14/clojure-and-large-result-sets.html, but I get about the same execution time for each.

FWIW, same result when doing `.println java.lang.System/out` (not surprising), and using with-query-results*:

```
(defn test-sql2 []
  (sql/with-connection (db-connection)
    (sql/with-query-results* ["select * from users order by username asc"]
      (fn [row] (println "User" (row :first_name) (row :last_name))))))
```

same, same.

Comment: What are your times like if you just manipulate the raw result set with Clojure?

Comment: @Bill not sure what you have in mind. Doesn't help it's my first day of Clojure :-)

Comment: @Bill I did the test it's in my answer, strangely times are even worse... There seems to be some kind of magic happening behind. At first I was thinking it was due to JIT, I copied jdbc to jdbc2 (source file) and used it from repl, after several runs times have converged. Passing `ResultSet` to the caller somehow magically increases runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing... As it turns out, the relatively poor performance was due to running my test code as part of a simple web app (I know, that doesn't make sense in the context of this question), which I ran with `lein ring server` which I guess is the same as running it using `repl` (I just didn't make that connection). When I tried compiling and packaging with `lein uberjar` and then executed that jar with `java -jar`, it gave me comparable performance to the Java app.

Comment: It's good to know that you found a fix, I guess I'll remove my "answer" now.

Comment: Though it looked like you had some interesting findings as well @IvanKoblik :-) My code in clojure is nearly twice as slow, but that's acceptable for my case, and furthermore, the tests aren't equal enough to draw a hard conclusion on it. I'm just happy I didn't find a deal breaker, as I love the little I've done with Clojure so far.